# Overriding a .equals() method

Tags: java, linked-list, equals

So basically I have a simple `remove` function that takes students out of my list if the IDs are matching. When writing this method I use `==` since `s.getId()` returns a primitive type. But I wrote a `.equals` method that should override it but now I can't call the `.equals` on `s.getId()`.

`equals` method in class `Student`:

```
public boolean equals(StudentIF other) {
    if (other == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.id == other.getId()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then my `remove` method which is in class `LL`:

```
public boolean remove(StudentIF s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StudentLLNode current = head;
    if (s == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (s.getId() == (head.getStd().getId())) {
        // StudentLLNode top = head;
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
        return true;
    } else {
        StudentLLNode previous, next;
        previous = current;
        next = current.getNext();
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.getNext();
            if (s.getId() == (current.getStd().getId())) {
                previous.setNext(next);
                size--;
                return true;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: By default `equals` expects an `Object` not a `StudentIF`, if you add the `@Override` annotation to your `equals` method you will receive a compiler error as you are not actually not overriding a method of any parent class

Comment: Why is that not an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The equals method receive an Object as parameter, here is how NetBeans automatically generates an equals method for a class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Person other = (Person) obj;
    if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Object class `equals` method takes the input of type `Object`. Correct signature for `equals` method is:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

`@Override` annotation is a great help to determine whether you have correctly overridden a method.

From [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> When overriding a method, you might want to use the @Override
>   annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a
>   method in the superclass. If, for some reason, the compiler detects
>   that the method does not exist in one of the superclasses, then it
>   will generate an error.